# What is the relationship between NSImageView and NSImageCell?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nsimageview

It seems that if I create an `NSImageView` in code, there is no way to have the image automatically scale proportionally up if the `NSImageView` becomes bigger than the image itself. (an odd omission)

On the other hand, if I create the `NSImageView` in IB, it seems to somehow attach an `NSImageCell` to the `NSImageView` and the `NSImageCell` has an option to scale proportionally up and down, which is what I want.

But in IB, I can't seem to understand the relationship between the `NSImageView` and the `NSImageCell`. I can't delete the `NSImageCell` from the `NSImageView` and I don't see the connection in bindings or anywhere else.

How do I get the functionality of the `NSImageCell` when creating the `NSImageView` in code?

Sorry if this is obvious, but I'm used to `UIImageViews` and they're definitely different than `NSImageView`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to scale up using `[NSImageView setImageScaling:NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown]`. Have you had trouble with that? You can also access the cell for any `NSControl` using `-cell`.

As for the separation of cells from controls (views), this is a hold-over from the days of much less powerful computers (some NeXT computers only had 8MB of memory). Cells provide a lighter-weight object that does not require some of the overhead of a full view. This is important in cases where a lot of elements might exist, such as in a matrix or a table. Cells are designed to be easier to copy and reuse, much like `UITableViewCell`. Like `UITableViewCell`, the same `NSCell` may be used repeatedly to draw different content. Cells also share some singletons. For example, there is typically only one field editor (`NSTextView`) shared by most cells. It just gets moved around as needed as the user selects different text fields to edit.

In a world where the first iPhone had 10x the memory of a NeXT and desktops commonly have 1000x the memory, some of the choices in `NSCell` don't make as much sense. Since 10.7, OS X has moved some things away from `NSCell`. `NSTableView` now supports `NSView` cells as well as `NSCell` cells. When iPhoneOS was released, `UITableView` got started on views from the beginning. (Of course an iPhone table view is minuscule compared to an OS X table view, so it was an easier choice for more reasons than just available memory.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have way more experience in iOS than Mac OS and made the bad assumption that they were more alike. I didn't even realize that all NSControls have an NSCell...including NSImageView. Thanks again.

Comment: iPhone benefited from almost 25 years of lessons in how to best implement an ObjC framework. For those of us who were working in Cocoa before iPhone, the original iPhoneOS was an incredible moment, filled mostly with "that's so familiar, but UIKit is much easier." On the other hand, UIWebView is a pale, sad little shadow of OS X's WebView. And TextKit/UITextView is pathetic compared to CocoaText/NSTextView. And the tiny subset of features available in iOS's Security.framework… Ok, so OS X is still better in many places, but UIKit is still beats AppKit.

Comment: I was wondering why your name looked so familiar...then I saw the copy of Pushing the Limits on my desk. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're confused is that the documentation on `-[NSImageView setImageScaling:]` is wrong, where it lists the possible scaling choices.  If you look up `NSImageScaling`, you will find another choice `NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown`.